# How do I set a cell value to stay 1/1/current year until next year?

Tags: google-sheets

I need for a cell to stay as Jan 1 of the current year (that date sets the condition of a year to date filter). I cant figure out a way to use the YEAR function, or any other function, to make it so that cell stays that date but then next year will update to Jan 1 of that new year.

Answer (score 2):

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1)
```

- Uses [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984) to get the current date
- [YEAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061) to grab the year
- [DATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969) to build the date

### TODAY vs. NOW

Sheets has two functions [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984) and [NOW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981) that will return the current date in a formula.

- [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984) returns the current date as a date value with no time component.
- [NOW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981) returns the current date and time as a date value.

Comment: perfect thanks a whole heap!